ROS2 colcon build outputs "Summary: 0 packages finished"
I am creating a workspace with colcon. I create a folder src/ in the folder I want to create the workspace, create a talker node in src/, and then from root I execute "colcon build".
However, it outputs "Summary: 0 packages finished" and I can't run the node.

What is the file structure inside of the package ros_ws/src/<package_name>/?

only the scrip .py, noticed i missed the package structure document and so, thanks!
